# exec and PATH on heroku with buildpacks

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, child-process, buildpack

I use [this buildpack](https://github.com/abernier/heroku-buildpack-casperjs) in order to use [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) on heroku.

Once my app created, I check my `PATH`

```
$ heroku config:get PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/vendor/phantomjs/bin:/app/vendor/casperjs/bin
```

OK, casperjs is in here!

--

*Procfile*

```
scraper: node scraper.js
```

*scraper.js*

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('casperjs casper-script.js');
```

--

But when I launch the scraper process, it crashes with the following logs:

```
2012-10-09T02:23:38+00:00 heroku[scraper.1]: Starting process with command `node scraper.js`
2012-10-09T02:23:39+00:00 app[scraper.1]: bash: node: command not found
```

---

Why [`exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) does not find `casperjs` which is in the `PATH` ?

PS: I tried with [`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) but no more luck...

**[EDIT]:** a testable gist here https://gist.github.com/3856317

Comment: are you sure it's the `casperjs` command that is failing and not `node` command?

Comment: @vinayr: it seems your are right, I simply tried `heroku run node` and get the `bash: node: command not found`. But how is it possible: I have a decent `package.json` so this app should be detected as a node one... Any clue? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

@vinayr: [you were right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792191/exec-and-path-on-heroku-with-buildpacks#comment17295473_12792191), neither `exec` nor `casperjs` command was involved in this issue, it was `node` which was the `command not found`!

I thought installing a buildpack with `phantomjs` and `casperjs` (eg: [heroku-buildpack-casperjs](https://github.com/misza222/heroku-buildpack-casperjs)) would have kept node capabilities for my app, but it does not seem so.

To make it work (node+phantomjs+casperjs) I rather had to fork the [heroku-buildpack-nodejs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) buildpack and add `phantomjs`/`casperjs` binaries to it, which I could have called: [heroku-buildpack-**nodejs**-casperjs](https://github.com/abernier/heroku-buildpack-nodejs).

In other words, when using a custom buildpack, you have to include the node support yourself .

Comment: Or you can use the multipacks, which is nice so you don't have to bundle everything. https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi